# Pre-sale Exp-resso question re: save for later and re-orders

Tags: expresso-store

We have a client who would like a e-commerce site where the product would have about a dozen options that the customer would have to work through before getting a final price. Because of the technical nature of the product, they would like customers to be able to save the cart, and come back to it later to edit  or complete the purchase. Would this be possible with Exp-resso, and would it require any custom scripting?

Also, if a customer places an order for multiple variations of a product, would they be able to go back and re-order one of the variations, but at that same time make a change to the options for the re-order?

Answer (score 1):

Exp:resso Store has good pre-sales and post-sales support, and this sounds like a good question to ask through such channels.

More information on how to access support through the [VMG/Exp:resso Support Page](https://www.exp-resso.com/support) - I would email them but imagine there might be a slight delay in getting a reply as it is Thanksgiving Weekend in USA currently.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar on a Store site.

Using https://eeharbor.com/favorites logged in members can add entries (products) to their favourites list. Then with Store's Product form tag they can load up their list and order everything in one go, or select how many of each item is required.